# How to send message to JMS queue using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jms

I have made a web-server using node.js, now on my client side (which I have made using java-script), when a user clicks send button, instead of a post request (XMLHttpRequest), I want to send the data to JMS queue. How can I implement that in javascript.

Comment: Try Kaazing WebSocket Gateway  https://developer.kaazing.com/documentation/jms/3.5/dev-js/dev-jms-js-cookbook.html#sending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMS is a Java-only API. There is no way to make JavaScript implement Java-API unless you actually run the JS on top of java (Rhino or whatever). But that does not seems to be the case here.

Theoretically - it's possible to implement a [C++ wrapper using JNI](http://codemesh.com/products/jmscourier/) to talk to java classes that can use JMS. That wrapper then has to be adapted to Node/V8 extension.. Well, it's a lot of error prone work. **Don't go this way.**

The solution is not to use JMS. Most JMS implementations (ActiveMQ, IBM WebSphere MQ, etc.) usually have multiple ways to communicate with it. Usually there is a C/C++ client that can be used by a Node.js extension.

There are also standardized wire-protocols that JMS brokers commonly supports that can be used with existing Node.js extensions. [AMQP 1.0](https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10), [MQTT](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js), [STOMP](https://github.com/benjaminws/stomp-js). Also, many message brokers have some possibility (addon or similar) to accept messages through HTTP.

So please explore what possible communication methods your JMS implementation has.

As a fallback solution, simply write a small java program that listen to HTTP and produces JMS messages that you can call from your Node.js app.